# How to pass data from one viewController to another without using segues?

Tags: ios, swift, viewcontroller

In my First ViewController:

```
var storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
var controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "backGroundController") as! BackGroundWithContainer
delegate?.myFunction(float: floatItryToPass)
```

In my second VC:

```
let whiteView = UIView()
@IBOutlet var TopBarView: UIView!

func takeScrollUpFloat(float: CGFloat) {

    print("scrollUpFloatTaker: ", float) //works fine
    whiteView.center.y = view.frame.height //bad access error here
    TopBarView.center.y = view.frame.height //found nil error here
}
```

The difficulty is really to change values that are defined in the second ViewController. How can I solve this without actually calling the segue? I know there are a zillion ways to do it when opening the view but I have to solve it WITOUT loading the second view again. Second View is currently running.

Comment: looks like your iboutlet TopBarView isnt connected via storyboard. Connect it, or initialize it somehow.

Comment: btw. the code is very confusing . topbar is one word, so the camel case is wrong. tobbarView. same for backgroundView 

Comment: Quick and dirty way, use NSNotification centre to communicate between. One board cast one observe

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to solve it

```
var storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
var secondController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "backGroundController") as! BackGroundWithContainer
secondController.passedFloat = floatItryToPass
```

Now in your second view controller

```
var passedFloat: CGFloat!
let whiteView = UIView()
@IBOutlet var TopBarView: UIView!

override func viewDidLoad() {

    print("scrollUpFloatTaker: ", float) //works fine
    // no bad access error here since your view is loaded, i.e viewDidLoad
    whiteView.center.y = view.frame.height 
    // all your IBOutlet variables also get values by the time viewDidLoad
    // is called, so you won't be getting nil for your TopBarView
    TopBarView.center.y = view.frame.height //found nil error here
}
```

The first